# In intellij idea, how to browse a file locally after I configured an FTP?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, ide

Before I make any FTP configuration, when I right click on an "index.html" file and select **Run "index.html"**, this file will be opened in a browser window with the address **localhost:8080/index.html**. The **Run Tool Window** pops up:
[image]

However, after I configured an FTP:
[image]

every time when I right click on the index.html file and select **Run**, the file will always be opened with the address vimer2.java.jspee.net/index.html. I want it to be opened locally as before, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the steps listed on the page below:

Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog by choosing File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for OS X, and click Web Browsers under Tools.

More details can be seen here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-browsers.html